# Project WWT images to a planar area

Tags: coordinate-system, worldwind

I'm a software developer and have no real experience working with geographic information. So please, bear with me.

I am developing a 3D tool with a 3D-area based on photos (photogrammetry). It is georeferenced to be able to extract WGS84 coordinates.

I can also create a different number of assets (lines, comments etc.) in this scene, that also get WGS84 coordinates based on their position in the scene.

Now I am working with World Wind tiles describing the same area. I want to project the World Wind tiles to a planar area, and have it georeferenced (so that the images like houses, lakes, streets etc. on the tiles have their correct geographic position). World Wind tiles are usually described in Palte Carree projection, but I get it with WGS84 (lat, long).

I have tried to calculate the tile delta, convert it to sweref99TM (to get it in meter) and then transform the assets to the World Wind tiles view, but I get what I experience as a constant offset (see images)

[image: 3D-view]
[image]

Notice the line offset to the building on the image to right.

So, what I want is to project World Wind tiles so that they are aligned to a planar (x,y) scope, where each unit is a meter in the real world. I want to know a reference point (for example the geo reference [0,0]) and then just add x and y to locate the correct geo point.

For example:

> Local =    Sweref99TM
>
> [0,0]  =    [135000, 6280000]
>
> [10,20] =   [135010, 6280020]
>
> [-10,120] = [134990, 6280120]

Here is an overview of the current different views.

[image: 3D overview]
[image: WWT overview]

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough or asking maybe a stupid question, but I'm stumped, and can't get this to work as expected.